# Bootstrap Mobile-Navbar not collapsed

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In the mobile Version the navbar is not collapsing... Can somebody help. Does anybody see my mistake?I copy the source from bootstrap but it didn't work. it does not work because I work with react?
I would be grateful for any help

file App.js

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
//Partikeln importieren

import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
//Hier importiert man seine Komponenten
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Header from "./components/Header";
...
...
...
```

file Navbar code

```
import React from 'react'
import Logo from "../img/logo_large.png"
// React Font awesome imports
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faBars } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
//React-scroll install

//Navbar
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div className="container">
                {/*Logo variable von oben*/}
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img className="Logo" src={Logo} /> </a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} style={{ color: "#fff" }} />
                </button>

                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item active">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#about" >About Me<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#experiences">Experiences</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#abilities">Abilities</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#freetime">Freetime</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav >
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `div` element with the `container` name.